# Strange Syntax in C++

Tags: c++, qt, syntax

Recently I've been facing a really strange way to write a protoype :

```
void myProto( QList<::myObject::myStruct> myStructList );
```

And I'd like to know what does "<::" and ">" mean ?

Thanks !

Comment: Hint, `<::` is not a single token. Split into `<` and `::`.

Comment: Read more on Qt [containter class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/containers.html) to get some idea..

Comment: Interesting to note that `<::` would be considered as `[:`, because `<:` is an alternative token for `[`, if it weren't for a special rule in §2.5: "[...] if the next three characters are `<::` and the subsequent character is neither `:` nor `>`, the `<` is treated as a preprocessor token by itself and not as the first character of the alternative token `<:`."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`QList` is a template, and `QList<Type>` is a specialization of that template, with the actual type `::myObject::myStruct`.

The `::` is the scope resolution operator, which tells the compiler to look for `myStruct` in the scope of `myObject`, which itself is at global scope.

Comment: Aww ! Okay ! Hm, sorry for such a simple question ! But thanks a lot for all your answers !

Answer (score 4):

```
::myObject::myStruct
```

means refer to `myStruct` defined in class (or namespace) `myObject` which is located at global scope.

```
<>
```

A *type* goes inside these brackets and it indicates the specialization of the template for that *type*.

Answer (score 0):

Compile the following program

```
struct A // GLOBAL A
{
    void f()
    { }
};

namespace nm
{
    struct A // nm::A
    { };

    template <class T>
    struct B
    {
        T a;

    };

    void f1(B<A> b) // WILL NOT COMPILE
    {
        b.a.f();
    }

    void f2(B< ::A> b)  // WILL COMPILE
    {
        b.a.f();
    }
}

int main()
{

}
```

`nm::f1` will not compile

`nm::f2` will compile

This is because `::A` (the global A) has a `f` member
and
`nm::A` doesn't have a `f` member.

Comment: In fact, the real problem I had was that I had a compilation problem with '<::' I had to split it with a whitespace to make it be accepted by my compiler ... isn't that strange ?

Comment: It's G++. I had some errors, blabla with -fpermissive that could make the compiler ignore the Warning.
The core error was the following : "note '<:' is an alternate spelling for '['. Insert whitespace between '<' and '::'.
I found that so weird that I wanted to ask here because I couldn't figure anyhow why this would not work.

Comment: I did more research right now, it seems that '<::' is not accepted as a 'template arguement list' so is '>>' within a 'nested template argument list'.
What I can't figure out is why this worked under MSVC and not with G++ ?

Comment: @Xaltar - `>>` changed in C++11 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1757.html - maybe `<::` also did. The problem with `<::` is that `<:` is a digraph.

Comment: Oh. Okay. I guess I'll use '< ::' now. Thanks for the link ! Edit : No more compilation problems. Thx boys :)